# Android force-close on Google maps: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: loading_tile_android

Tags: android, exception, crash, mapactivity

One of my Android users is getting a force-close when launching Google Map (MapActivity class) inside my application. He gets a MissingResourceException. He's the only one complaining so far, and he is using Vanilla Tazz phone. The Google maps application itself works well on his device. It looks like it's something specific to Vanilla Tazz. I tried to find a fix online but have not been successful. Here's the Android error log:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at ...
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2449)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9027)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.<clinit>(MapActivity.java:295)
 ... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Could not find required resource  
  com.android.internal.R$drawable.loading_tile_android    (java.lang.NoSuchFieldException:   loading_tile_android)
 at com.google.android.maps.InternalR.getField(InternalR.java:65)
 at com.google.android.maps.InternalR.get(InternalR.java:39)
 at com.google.android.maps.InternalR.access$000(InternalR.java:28)
 at com.google.android.maps.InternalR$drawable.get(InternalR.java:112)
 at com.google.android.maps.InternalR$drawable.<clinit>(InternalR.java:119)
 ... 15 more
```

I would appreciate if anyone can suggest anything to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you'll find a fix for this: it sounds like the ROM was built without that resource as part of the OS image. They'll probably need a new ROM to get around that.

Comment: You are probably right. I asked the user to install the Google maps update and pointed out to a patch I found. I don't know if he'll do this, because it's not easy to most people, but I will let you know if he does and whether this fixes the crash.